# How do I create "groups of users" and set permissions in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server, and I need to do something like the following:

- Create a group of users that will allow them to only SELECT from Table 1, but be able to SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT INTO Tables 2 and 3;
- Create another group of users that will allow them to SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT INTO all three of the aforementioned tables

All three of the tables are in the same database.

May someone please provide some sample code so that I can accomplish something like that? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, you need to first create a [login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for each user and add each [user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to the database. Logins allow users to connect to the SQL Server instance and database users allow users to connect to the database. Once these are created, create a [database role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with the users as [members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to [grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) object permissions to the role.

The annotated example script below uses SQL logins but you can instead use Windows user or group accounts depending on your environment.

```
--create SQL logins to authenticate users and authorize them to connect to the SQL Server instance
CREATE LOGIN UserA WITH PASSWORD='UserAP@ssw0rd';
CREATE LOGIN UserB WITH PASSWORD='UserBP@ssw0rd';
CREATE LOGIN UserC WITH PASSWORD='UserCP@ssw0rd';
CREATE LOGIN UserD WITH PASSWORD='UserDP@ssw0rd';

--create database users (mapped to login of same name) to authorize users to connect to this database
USE YourDatabase;

--add database users
CREATE USER UserA;
CREATE USER UserB;
CREATE USER UserC;
CREATE USER UserD;

--Create a group of users that will allow them to only SELECT from Table 1, but be able to SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT INTO Tables 2 and 3;
USE YourDatabase;

--create role with members
CREATE ROLE Group1Role;
ALTER ROLE Group1Role
    ADD MEMBER UserA;
ALTER ROLE Group1Role
    ADD MEMBER UserB;

--grant object permissions to role
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Table1 TO Group1Role;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON dbo.Table1 TO Group1Role;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON dbo.Table2 TO Group1Role;
GO

--Create another group of users that will allow them to SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT INTO all three of the aforementioned tables
USE YourDatabase;

--create role with members
CREATE ROLE Group2Role;
ALTER ROLE Group2Role
    ADD MEMBER UserC;
ALTER ROLE Group1Role
    ADD MEMBER UserD;

--grant object permissions to role
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON dbo.Table1 TO Group2Role;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON dbo.Table2 TO Group2Role;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON dbo.Table3 TO Group2Role;
GO
```

Comment: @FelixAn Note that if you are using **Active Directory**, then you can either create a `LOGIN` per individual **User** or just create a `LOGIN` per **Active Directory Group** that those **Users** already belong to. Presumably you'd only need two **Active Directory Groups** here for a total of two `LOGIN`s, one for the more restrictive permissions and one for the less restrictive permissions. You can even use one of the existing **Active Directory Groups** like **[Domain Users]** if you wanted to assign default permissions for all **Users** on the domain.

Comment: This is great; thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in sql server is to create a group of permission.

They are called Database **Roles**. You can use pre-build roles or create some new.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15

About the group of users you can't with the sql authentication but if you use the windows authentication you can relay on local user groups (uased as login in sql server) or active directory user groups (add them as login in sql server)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login?view=sql-server-ver15